# Azure Logic App authenticate with WebApp using MSI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

Has anyone ever managed to implement MSI authentication between a LogicApp and a WebApp? (assuming this is even possible). The only examples I am managing to find are to use MSI with services like Keyvault, Storage etc.

Comment: What operation do you want to do between the logic app and web app via MSI auth?

Comment: So basically I want to eliminate basic auth etc. I want to be able to call(GET/POST/etc) our own API via MSI authentication, the problem is that I am only finding examples of getting a token from an API to call other Azure services. It goes without saying that the API then would not be accesible unless MSI authention is used.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, your API is hosted in Azure web app, and you want to use MSI to call the API in logic app, if so, you could follow the steps below.

1. Navigate to your web app in the portal -> `Authentication / Authorization` -> enable the Azure AD auth of your web app, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings).

**Note:** Please select `Create new AD App` like below, then Azure will configure the AD App automatically for you, this can avoid many configuration issues.

[image]

At last, select `Log in with Azure Active Directory`, it will be like below after all the configurations.

[image]

2. Navigate to the logic app in the portal -> `Identity` -> [enable the system-assigned identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity#enable-system-assigned-identity-in-azure-portal).
3. In the logic app designer, use the Http action like below(In my sample, to test it easily, I use azure function instead of web app, they are the same logic, just use web app in your case), replace the `Audience` with the URL of your web app.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Will try this out and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I am working on this same problem and it does not work.  My app is attempting interactive flow so I get a 302 which fails the entire run.  If I had the token directly then I could add it as an authorization header and it would work.

Comment: Additional info: I was having problems with this, until I realized that I was using the authentication flow from Visual Studio vs. the one built into Azure App Services.  The auth flow using Visual Studio does not support silent authentication (called "server directed flow" in the documentation).

You can read about the Auth flow here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#authentication-flow

Answer (score 0):

It can be done out of box. You can call `MSI` authenticated `Web API` from Logic App by following below simple steps:

1. Add `MSI` to your Logic App.
2. Add `RBAC` for Logic App in your Web API's App Service.
3. Add `HTTP action` with settings like below in your Logic App to call Web API (Don't add `Audience` and fill up other details of the `API`):

   [image]

For more details, visit [Authenticate access to Azure resources by using managed identities in Azure Logic Apps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity#prerequisites)

Comment: I do not want to call Storage or any other service. I want my API to use MSI authentication when receiving requests. Is this possible? (to clarify I do not want to get a token within my API to call Azure services)

Comment: I have explained the same thing, sorry if I was not clear. It is to call MSI authenticated Web API from Logic App. Correct me if I wrongly understood your question.

Comment: Ok, I will go over your answer again to see what I might have missed. As my API is still accessible from the outside without using MSI or anything.

Comment: For this, pls add MSI in your Web API first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity

Comment: Does this answer help you?

Comment: Hi singhh-msft , sorry was away for some time, I will try this asap this week and get back to you. I still have to resolve this problem so thanks for your help!